# JavaScript - match 3 characters on typed one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, nestjs

I have some records in database that are containing Serbian latin letters (ć, č, đ, ž, š).

I've done search functionality in backend (nestjs) to search all columns in table that contain typed characters on frontend (react).

How could I search these latin letters when typed character is for example c (this should look for all 3 characters with same "base" -> c, č, ć). Same should be done with the others.

I tried some regex, but never got desired result.

Any basic ideas how should I do this?

Comment: to be honest, if you can redo the architecture, id replace all occurrences of those letters with just c and map it elsewhere. then youd have 2 representations: the text without the special characters and the representation holding the index and the type of the special character

Comment: @StrahinjaL did you check our answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably utilize `localCompare` for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

> The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a
> reference string comes before, or after, or is the same as the given
> string in sort order. In implementations with Intl.Collator API
> support, this method simply calls Intl.Collator.
>
> A negative number if referenceStr occurs before compareString;
> positive if the referenceStr occurs after compareString; 0 if they are
> equivalent.

An example:

```
let a = 'caknut';
let b = 'ćaknut';
console.log(a.localeCompare(b, 'sr', { sensitivity: 'base' })); // 0
```

A `0` indicates that both strings are equivalent.

Comment: This thid the trick! I called recursive function that examines every typed letter and with this check it tries all three possible solutions with base c and then I just replaced those characters! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `postgres` tag, this can be done using [SIMILAR](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)

You only need to construct your right part, inside `%%` so as to include these variations

```
select * from yourtable
where yourcolumn SIMILAR TO '%(c|ć|č)%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const string = 'this is normal but this ć, č, đ, ž, š not'

const normalizeMap = {
  'č': 'c',
  'ć': 'c',
  'đ': 'd',
  'š': 's',
  'ž': 'z'
}

const normalize = string => Object
  .entries(normalizeMap)
  .reduce((res, [raw, normalized]) =>  res.replace(new RegExp(raw, 'g'), normalized), string)

console.log(normalize(string))
```